# Как получить список chrome-настроек конкретного сайта через js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Я пишу расширение для chrome для одного конкретного сайта. Мне нужно определить, разрешил ли пользователь автоматическое воспроизведение звука на этом сайте через настройки этого сайта по ссылке. Даю пример настроек ЭТОГО сайта.

chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fru.stackoverflow.com%2F

Могу ли я с открытой вкладкой сайта https://ru.stackoverflow.com/, получить список настроек, которые сделал пользователь по ссылке выше?

*Делаю такой костыль, потому что не смог осилить автоплей нормально. Мое звуковое уведомление, которое я встраиваю на сайт, блокируется chrome'ом, мол воспроизведение должно быть вызвано действием пользователя и только.*